How can authors use LLMs (like ChatGPT) without accidentally plagiarising?
Leading scientific venues in machine learning allow LLMs as a “general-purpose assist tool,” provided that authors assume “full responsibility for the contents.” Such policies raise the question of how to assess whether LLM suggestions are problematic.
This post specifically concerns plagiarism, i.e., (unintentionally) copying the work of other (human) authors by using LLMs as a tool.
This raises the question of whether it is possible for the authors to detect plagiarism in LLM output:
If authors can reliably detect such plagiarism in LLM output, they can exclude it from their papers.
Conversely, if they cannot reliably detect it, plagiarism could unintentionally be incorporated into an author’s work.
Example
Consider authors writing a paper with a new mathematical theorem as its central contribution.
They use an LLM to help them edit the draft, brainstorm, and develop ideas.
This LLM suggests editing improvements (such as improved grammatical structures and stylistic improvements) and broader changes, such as improvements in narrative structure and new analogies.
The authors check these suggestions and partially integrate them into their draft.
Crucially, the authors detect scenarios where the LLM suggests exact copies or core contributions of other works, as they use an automatic plagiarism checker and have a broad knowledge of their field.
The authors have no unethical intentions.
Some may argue that the above practice could still constitute plagiarism, as the author's manuscript may contain underlying structures derived from other papers, such as specific analogies or the overall organization of ideas.
Crucially, the authors could not identify this content to exclude it from their work:
Detection would be possible if the authors knew the reference works the LLM used to generate its output. However, since these references are unknown and may span the entire body of academic literature, comparing the new work against all paragraphs of all existing works would be intractable. Automated plagiarism detection checkers are also unreliable, as they often miss non-verbatim similarities.
Is there a consensus on the above question?
Is it always practically possible for the authors to detect problematic LLM suggestions (to exclude them from their works), or are there areas where using LLMs as a tool is always unethical (as one cannot rule out plagiarism)?
LLMs as tools and not authors
Many policies of leading scientific venues define LLMs like ChatGPT as tools, not authors (as they cannot be held accountable for their output). In this view, the text in a manuscript is ultimately the product of an author, who decides to which extent to use its tools. Tools can produce harmful and harmless output, and the author must distinguish the two. This raises the question of to what extent this is possible.
Example: Consider using LLMs as a spell and grammar checker, which many people would not consider plagiarism. Conversely, using LLMs to copy other works verbatim is clearly (easily detectable) plagiarism. This post concerns scenarios located between these extremes.
What this post is not about
This post:

assumes that authors do not blindly copy/paste LLM output into their manuscripts,
does not advocate for using LLMs as a complete replacement for human skills, and
does not discuss whether LLMs can improve scientific work in principle.


The concern I have with ChatGPT is that it seemingly tries to sound confident about its results despite doing no kind of verification of its own. You've probably had those students who, when they don't know how to solve a problem, will try to "BS" and fudge or obscure any steps they are unsure about. Would you let one of those students draft your paper for you?

By "safe" you seem to mean "don't get caught", rather than "do no harm". I think it is unsafe on both counts. Why do you focus on the first only???

Even though you have dropped the word "safe" from the title question, you are still focused on getting caught, not on assuring the validity of your results.

@Nate Eldredge: The user can verify the LLM output. If an LLM (or student) output is “BS” to me, I would simply not use it. I'd argue that "BS" (e.g., a mathematically incorrect statement) is usually identifiable (at least in the context of writing a scientific paper). However, I wonder whether all problematic LLM output is identifiable (e.g., some forms of plagiarism as outlined in the main post).

@Buffy: I edited the title to remove the word “safe.” Thanks for the hint!
Why would you think that it does harm? Do you think there is a way to use LLMs in science without doing harm?
Why do you think that I focus on “not getting caught”? This is not my intention. I am happy to edit the main post to avoid misunderstandings if helpful.

LLMs have no mind, they have no ethics or morals, they have no understanding. They can't explain their reasoning (having none). What they produce based on the writings of others is inherently plagiarism. And you have tagged it as plagiarism, revealing your motivation.

@Buffy: LLM output is only plagiarism if it is sufficiently similar to the work of others, not generally. I ask whether it is, in principle, possible for authors to detect all cases when LLM output is plagiarism (to avoid unintentionally placing plagiarism in a paper).

You mean, "to avoid unintentionally placing detectable plagiarism in a paper". I know you don't think that, nor will you accept that characterization, but that is the root of it. Sorry to be blunt.

@Buffy: Plagiarism (as characterized in the main post) is always detectable, e.g., by the authors of a plagiarized paper. I want to avoid a scenario where a paper contains plagiarism (included by an LLM) that is not reliably detectable by the authors, both for ethical and practical reasons.

"The user can verify the LLM output." Easy to say, hard to do.  As humans, we're used to verifying the work of other humans, ideally ones who write in good faith and make an honest effort at correctness.  There's a difference between that and LLMs which, in effect, actively try to sound confident and convincing about stuff whose correctness they have no reason to believe in.  It's the difference between an inexperienced collaborator who makes honest mistakes, and a deliberately deceptive adversary.

Plagiarism is when you take someone else's ideas and represent them as your own. Assuming the authors did not explicitly disclose that the text is AI-generated, the following:

plagiarism could unintentionally be incorporated

is impossible because "unintentional" is impossible. Accordingly, the question is moot. If the authors used ChatGPT, and didn't disclose it as such, they are plagiarizing and they know it.
PS: they are also breaking the ChatGPT end user license agreement, which prohibits representing the output as human-generated.

If authors used LLMs as spell checkers, would you consider this plagiarism? Should the authors then disclose the resulting text as “AI-generated”? Would others plagiarise when not disclosing the usage of the MS Word spell checker?

This argument is confidently presented but incorrect, akin to an LLM hallucination. Even fairly complex LLM-generated content could sometimes be included in academic papers without getting anywhere near plagiarism. For example, someone might use an LLM to implement an algorithm that they came up with, verify the implementation, use the results, and publish LLM-generated pseudocode in their paper after verifying the pseudocode as well. I don't think this would be plagiarism any more than not saying R was used to compute the results shown in Figure 5 (although acknowledging both would be good).
